# this codes output needs to be sent to a seperate text file, why does no work

Tags: python-3.x

i have got this piece of code to find the positions of the first occuring of that word and replace them into the actual program.
i have tried this

```
sentence = "ask not what you can do for your country ask what your country can do for you"
listsentence = sentence.split(" ")
d = {}
i = 0
values = []
for i, word in enumerate(sentence.split(" ")):
    if not word in d:
        d[word] = (i + 1)
    values += [d[word]]
print(values)



example = open('example.txt', 'wt')
example.write(str(values))

example.close()
```

how do i write this output to a seperate text file such as notepad.

Comment: notepad is an application, not a text file…

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code works- example.txt is created each time you run this program. You can check that in your directory this file exists.

If you want to open it right after closing it in your script add:

```
import os
os.system("notepad example.txt")
```